# What controls heart rate while workout?

Tags: heart-rate, performance, athletic-performance

I am 31 year old with moderate fitness. I cycle 3 times a week about 40 mins average and my heart rate monitor data shows I average more than many other people on strava. I know beats per minute may be considered as a fitness parameter and was wondering why people like Amanda Coker average out 115bpm after a 300+ km ride and mine turns out to be 140bpm for 10k ride.

What are the factors which control heart beats? Are there any contributing factors like hormones imbalance, blood count, adrenal fatigue etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about conditioning.

You have not stated for how long have you been cycling and am assuming not very long. The person you mentioned might also have sub 50 resting heart rate while yours would be in 70-90 range. Once you keep performing the same exercise over a period of time, your body/heart becomes very efficient in doing so. Basically the same 40 mins ride on same tempo would feel a lot easier after few weeks of continuous training. Even your average HRM would gradually lower as the energy expenditure goes down due to the cardio conditioning.

Answer (score 0):

Many things affect your heart rate. Illness, overtraining, the weather, medication, dehydration, stress...and the list goes on.

Be sure to do tons of aerobic work if you're just starting out and keep your heart rate below 75% of your maximum.  You should see your speed increase and your heart rate drop.  You might never have as low a heart rate as Amanda Coker, but it will be strong!